# can't go through simple JavaScript prototype's method

Tags: javascript

I have written some JavaScript code. It adds new function to NodeList type in this way:

```
NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(func) {
var len = this.length
for(var i=0;i<len;i++) func(this[i])
}
```

It is used somewhere else like that:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset").forEach(disappearFields)
```

All is really simple.

It works nice in chrome but firefox gives an error:

> document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset").forEach is not a function
>   [Break on this error] document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset").forEach(disappearFields)

disappearFields is short function:

```
function disappearFields(what) {
what.style.display = "none"
}
```

I have looked for any help in google but according to those information my code should work properly. I am not able to cope with that myself. Any help 'll be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid extending the DOM, you will find a lot issues, give a look to this article: [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.forEach = function(func) {
var len = this.length
for(var i=0;i<len;i++) func(this[i])
}
```

FireFox recognizes `document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")` as an HTMLCollection

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection

I think Safari recognizes it as a NodeList and IE as just an object.

Comment: Safari does recognize it as a NodeList.  Chrome and Safari are both WebKit browsers so this makes sense.

Comment: I don't know why, but my "firefox" didn't accept your solution. I modified the prototype of Object and now is ok. Maybe iceweasel - debian browser based on firefox - works diffrently.